# How Do I Find the Last Positional Parameter in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking to find the last positional parameter. I know to find the number of parameters is $# which logically is the last but I need to find and use what is in the last positional parameter.

It would be like if $# = 5, I want to do $5.

I have tried to do something like $$# or ${$#} as guesses but can't get it.

Instances where I would need to use it is in an if statement or declaring it to another variable or with echo.

I hope that is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for a shell function or are you trying to get the last argument on the previous command line?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want `${!#}`, which combines the argument count with indirection.

Comment: and `eval last=\$$#` for shells that lack indirection via `!`.

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: And I am guessing you can't assign t${!#} as a variable if thats what you meant. But eval last=\$$# worked for me. I think thats what you meant by lack of indirection

Answer (score 13):

This seems like a more direct approach:

```
${@: -1}
```

Some further information [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays). I'm not sure about portability outside of Bash.

Comment: Do not forget the space between  colon  (:) and minus (-), or yo'u'll get another behavior/command. In this way, you are defining a default parameter to $@ of it is null or unset.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way:

```
while [[ "$1" != "" ]];do
    last_parm=$1
    shift
done
echo $last_parm
```

Give a test:

```
$ ./test.sh 1 2 3 4 5
5
```

Comment: It is VERY important to note that this method eliminates all positional parameters, and makes all but the last inaccessible.  While in the limited context of the question this is a correct answer, in practice it will have undesirable side-effects for many realistic scenarios.  This approach is only acceptable as-is if you really don't care about anything but the last parameter.